# generate random Id using php

Tags: php, jquery

I print input list like this code :

PHP CODE:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {

    echo '<input "audio" class="" name="audio[]" >';

}
```

Output Is:

```
<input id="audio" class="" name="audio[]" >

<input id="audio" class="" name="audio[]" >
```

Now , I need to add a random character or name or id for each `input` Like this :

using random :

```
<input id="audio-Ms50Uiyt" class="" name="audio[]" >
<input id="audio-dY90iOOO" class="" name="audio[]" >
```

Using Number:

```
<input id="audio-1" class="" name="audio[]" >
<input id="audio-2" class="" name="audio[]" >
```

how do generate this using `PHP` (or jQuery)??

Comment: ID has to be unique. You shouldn't set the same ID for many elements.

Comment: Could the person who is handing out the downvotes please clarify him/her self?

Comment: @Ortix92 It wasn't me but as I can see - everyone of you have doubled IDs.

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean ?

Comment: OP asked for a specific feature. Everyone delivered that exact feature.

Comment: @Ortix92 Sure but with repeating his mistakes - it's not a good habit.

Comment: @hsz: Sorry, didn’t realize OP was still using the same ids twice (for input and accompanying div) in their example.

Comment: @hsz: why ID should be unique?! i need to add uplaod URL from file manager to Input and file manager sync with Input ID.

Comment: @user27133: IDs must be unique. :http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [`uniqid`](http://php.net/uniqid) function to generate random id:

Also ID has to be unique. You shouldn't set the same ID for many elements. Better way is to use `rel` tag to mark a relation

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $id = uniqid();
    echo '<input id="audio-' .  $id . '" class="" name="audio[]" >';
    echo '<div rel="audio-' .  $id . '"></div>';
}
```

Comment: @hsz: with you code for each DIV and input generate random unique id. So rel != input Id. this worked with one input not for one+1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $num = 1;
 foreach ($urls as $url) {

     echo '<input id="audio-'.$num.'" class="" name="audio[]" >';
     echo '<div id="audio-'.$num.'"></div>';
     $num++;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {

    echo '<input id="audio-'.$key.'" class="" name="audio[]" >';
    echo '<div id="audio-'.$key.'"></div>';
}
```

You can use the internal counting key of the foreach loop

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use this

```
$i = 1;

        foreach (urls as $url) {

            echo '<input id="audio-'.$i.'" class="" name="audio[]" >';
            echo '<div id="audio-'.$i.'">llllllll</div>';
            $i++;
        }
```